# Switch between ggplot and ggmap but retain the rest of the code?

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm building a function which automates the map plotting for users' data, with various options, one of which is to allow different map backgrounds, either Google satellite from `ggmap::get_map`, or a global coastline processed by `gbm.auto::gbm.basemap` (my own package). The problem is, the plot starting function needs to be different, either `ggmap` or `ggplot` respectively, but the rest of the plot block is the same. I tried putting this as an option in braces:

```
if (mapsource == "gbm.basemap") {
      ggplot() +
        ggspatial::layer_spatial(shape, col = "black")
    } else {
      ggmap::ggmap(myMap)
    } +
    stars::geom_stars(data = predabundstars |> sf::st_transform(3857), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    [more code, fill, theme, etc]
```

This works for the second option (else; ggmap):

[image: ggmap google]

But if `mapsource == "gbm.basemap"`, it runs the initial code in braces but nothing after:

[image: basemap fail]

If I run the ggplot code outside of braces it works fine, so there's nothing wrong with the data, therefore it must be the 'braces to start a plot' bit:

[image: basemap]

I tried switching it around (`ggmap` then `basemap`), and doing them independently (`if ggmap`, `if basemap`) but still no dice. Is this a peculiarity of `ggplot`? Does anyone know a way around it? I suppose the 'nuclear' option would be duplicating the whole plot code block, one with `ggmap`, one with `ggplot`, and `ifelse`-ing them. I presume that would work but it also kinda sucks that it's that clunky.

Thanks in advance for any intel!

Comment: You could assign to an object in the if statement `if(...){p <-  ggmap::ggmap(myMap)} ...` then start fresh outside the if statement `p <- p + .... ` (haven't tested this as data is not super easily available but assuming it works with no if statement this should work and I have done similar before).

Comment: Worked a treat, great idea, thanks Sarah. Do you wanna make this an answer so I can upvote?

Comment: Sure, felt like there wasn't quite enough content for an answer but if it did the trick then I guess it counts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend assigning to an object within the if statement and then using this after the if statement:

```
if (mapsource == "gbm.basemap") {
      p <- ggplot() +
        ggspatial::layer_spatial(shape, col = "black")
    } else {
      p <- ggmap::ggmap(myMap)
    }
p <- p + stars::geom_stars(data = predabundstars |> sf::st_transform(3857), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```